# Whenever I try to load a static file, it gives error 404 not found

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Whenever I try to load a static file, it gives error 404 not found. However when checking what directory it looks in it shows /account/login/static/accounts/style.css, when account/login isn't even a directory. The error message is Not Found: /account/login/static/accounts/style.css

I've searched everywhere and can't find how to change the directory.

## Here is the settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   ]
```

---

## Here is my accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from django.urls import path
from accounts import views
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name="login")
    ]
```

---

## Here is my tutorial/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

---

## And here is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(r[enter image description here][1]equest, "accounts/login.html")[enter image description here][1]
```

Here is a image of my directory/files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdk0X.png

Comment: Can you post the line in your html file where you are trying to load the css file?

Answer (score 0):

Run command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and then clear that account prefix from your template addresses.
change this `accounts/login.html` to this `login.html`
there is more changes you should do in your template file login.html to load static files. I recommend you first read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/).